# Robocode Enemy class setDirection() calling

Tags: java, robocode

I'm programming Robocode and now I have a coding question:

I defined class `Enemy` to store enemy information (such as heading, bearing, velocity etc.) and in this class I also defined a private attribute named direction. Then I use the public getters and setters to allow my bot to call those properties. But when I use `enemy.setDirection(e.getDirection());`, NetBean IDE shows it as incorrect. Could someone help solve this problem?

```
public class Enemy {
    // ...
    private double direction;

    public double getDirection(ScannedRobotEvent e, AdvancedRobot me) {
        direction = e.getBearing() + me.getHeading();
        return direction;
    }

    public void setDirection(double direction) {
        this.direction = direction;
    }
}
```

Then in my robot class:

```
public class myBot extends AdvancedRobot {
    private Enemy enemy = new Enemy();

    public onScannedRobot(ScannedRobotEvent e) {
        enemy.setDirection(e.getDirection()); // Here is the problem
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you call `e.getDirection()` it is looking for that method in `ScannedRobotEvent`. But `getDirection()` has only been declared for the Enemy class.

Answer (score 0):

When you call the getDirection method, you have to input the properties, so in this case, a ScannedRobotEvent and an AdvancedRobot field.